# Arduino Presence Detector through Glass and Transparent Objects

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to measure the distance of a glass/transparent object using an IR sensor. Does anybody know of sensors that work for this task?

Note: it has to be reasonably small, so ultrasonic sensors won't do.

Comment: From what distance? What field of view? How many samples per second? In how many dimensions? How small? What's your budget? What transparent objects, besides glass?

Comment: Distance: 1 mm
Field Of View: I'm not sure what you mean but the object width is about 3 cm and the sensor will be placed at the center of the object.
Samples: 1 per Second
Dimensions: two dimensions
Size: 5mm diameter
Budget: USD 50-100$
Objects: Plastic + Glass + Black painted surface